# Demo Store Notice Cannot be Disabled in Magento 2 Admin Panel

Tags: magento2

I tried to turn off the demo store notice through the Admin panel system configuration, Unfortunately I encountered this error that says `Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Area is already set.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

**Error Image:**

[image]

Comment: are you logged with administrator in backend. or else ?

Comment: @Himanshu Hi, yes im logged in with admin account in the backend.

Comment: On right top corner, click your user name => Account Settings = > Interface Locale => set to US english , go back to settings and try to safe again. If this work something is wrong with your locals.

Comment: @BartZalas i tried to change the locale, unfortunately it is still not working.

Comment: Did you logout and cleaned cache also browser one?